# ng e2e --configuration=e2e in Azure DevOps running for a long time

Tags: angular, azure-devops, protractor, e2e-testing

I have an angular web page where I am trying to run E2E testing in Azure DevOps Pipeline.

But my end to end testing is running for a long time and does not produce any result.

Not sure what I am missing, I have shared my configuration below.

angular.json

```
"e2e": {
         "fileReplacements": [
              {
                      "replace": "src/app/core/services/auth.service.ts",
                      "with": "src/app/core/services/auth.service.mock.ts"
               }
            ]
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e --configuration=e2e"  
 }
```

protractor.conf.js

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--incognito"]
    }
  },
  chromeDriver: '../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_87.0.4280.88',
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/login',
  framework: 'custom',
  ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
```

My Pipele Yml:

```
- task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm Install'
      inputs:
        command: 'install'
        workingDir: './'
    - script: | 
                $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=chromedriver_87.0.4280.88
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'E2E Testing'
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        workingDir: './'
        customCommand: 'run e2e'
```

Comment: According to your description, I tested e2e test. But I cannot reproduce the same problem. Since it takes you long time , you could try to run the test with headless mode.  `args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--incognito"]` in protractor.conf.js

Comment: On the other hand, after you run the test, will you get an error message? You could share some log about this issue. You can also share your angular version（I use the 7.2.0）

Comment: I tried with the below options '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-dev-shm-usage' and it worked, not sure which options helped to run.. Regarding the error, I don't have any error since the test never exit!!

Comment: Do you mean that you change the option and the e2e test could run successfully and show the result?  As far as I know, -headless' and '--disable-gpu'  can improve the performance of chrome test. These two arguments should be helpful. You can try adding only these two arguments.  Headless Chrome gives you a real browser context without the memory overhead of running a full version of Chrome.

Comment: yes, I did mention that I changed the e2e options and will try about with just the option shared.

Comment: Feel free to let me know if it could work. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Rasmi. I converted my comment into an answer, you can check if it is the same as your test result. If yes, you may consider accept it .  If you have a new discovery, you can also share it in your answer, and then accept your answer. This will help other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running automated tests, I recommend to use the browser’s headless mode.

So you could add the `args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--incognito"]` in your `protractor.conf.js` file.

e2e tests can take long time to complete, due to elements on a page that the browser needs to load. Therefore, in some cases, it may be stuck because the element cannot be loaded. Headless testing gets rid of this load time, allowing you to cut your testing times significantly. In our tests with headless testing, we've seen a 30% reduction of test execution times.